# Can i ask the user to re-enter command line argument

Tags: c++, c, gcc, command-line-arguments

```
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
if(argc != 3) {
printf("Invalid number of arguments\n");
exit(1);
}}
```

Here i'm directly exiting the program if the **count** doesn't match the required **number of arguments.**

Is there any way to ask the user to re-enter the command line arguments if the number of arguments doesn't match the count? I mean without **exiting the program..**

Comment: Sure, but I don't see much point. Just bring up the last command and change the end.

Comment: `printf("Invalid number of arguments\n Please try again");`

Comment: @KarthikT: I want to re-enter the arguments without exiting the program. Can i?

Comment: @RaghuSrikanthReddy as chris mentioned command line arguements are typically collected as you have shown, with exit for invalid arguements. You could instead use `scanf` and parse it yourself, but the effort would not be worth it.

Comment: @Raghu: You really *don't* want to do that. Command line tools should work in conjunction with other tools and from within scripts etc - if you add unnecessary user interaction then you break this paradigm.

Comment: If you plan to get the missing arguments on program's startup... why even put arguments in the program through command line? Just ask them right away on startup, that will make it easier for the user and yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
std::string askUser(std::string const& question)
{   
     std::cout << question << "\n";

     std::string result;
     std::getline(std::cin, result);

     return result;
}   
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    std::string  arg1;
    std::string  arg2;
    std::string  arg3;

    arg1   = (argc > 1) ? std::string(argv[1]) : askUser("Please Enter Arg1");
    arg2   = (argc > 2) ? std::string(argv[2]) : askUser("Please Enter Arg2");
    arg3   = (argc > 3) ? std::string(argv[3]) : askUser("Please Enter Arg3");
 }
```

Comment: Loki's answer is much better than mine, I would use his prior to trying mine, for the reasons previously stated.

Comment: It somewhat misses the point - he wants to user to provide arguments, and, only if the count is wrong, ask again (for all of them, or just the additional ones? I'm not sure).

Comment: I think he just wants the user to enter the 3 arguments, be a pain, from the user's point of view, to keep typing in the same arguments... lol, if, of course, they manage to enter the wrong # of arguments multiple times.